# Htaccess redirect not working properly in cPanel

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

I am trying to add htaccess 301 redirect to redirect my old site to new domain. After changing everything and updating the htaccess, only main site url is redirected and all other urls are unaffected.

Example :

olddomain.com > newdomain.com (Works)
olddomain.com/file > newdomain.com/file (Doesn't work)

htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am also using cloudflare on Cpanel with Nginx.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue to me. Have you checked in your browser's console? Did you _really_ use a fresh anonymous browser instance to test?